# Orientation change in settings causes the app to crash

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

> java.lang.RuntimeException: [v0.1.70] Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stackexchange.marvin/com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.SettingsActivity}: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.SettingsActivity$SettingsFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

Android 4.4, version 0.1.70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.73, thanks!